# Run Perl script from CD?

Tags: script, compact-disc, perl

I've created a Perl script and burned it to a CD-ROM disc.  I would like to be able to run the script from the CD without having to copy it to some directory on the hard drive.  For some reason when it's burned to the CD it loses its permissions; particularly the execute permission.

Thoughts?

I think I can just enter "perl myscript.pl" but is it possible to burn the disc so that all I do is simply enter "./myscript.pl"?

Comment: Which Linux distribution (and version) are you running?

Comment: If you want permissions to stay, you need to use the Rock Ridge extensions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The iso9660 filesystem does not have an execute bit, so you must execute the file in a different way.

**Option 1: Run from Perl**

As you mentioned, you can run `perl ./myscript.sh`.

**Option 2: Remount DVD as executable**

sudo mount -o remount,exec /media/username/DVDNAME

**Option 3: Set default mount options for disc drive**

TBD: Differs by Linux distribution and version.

**Option 4: Use Rock Ridge Extensions**

> The [Rock Ridge Interchange Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rock_Ridge) (RRIP, IEEE P1282) is an extension
>   to the ISO 9660 volume format, commonly used on CD-ROM and DVD media,
>   which adds POSIX file system semantics ... [including] UNIX-style file
>   modes, user ids and group ids, and file timestamps.